# Unable to resolve: Compiled /not-found error for Nextjs react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, node-modules

I ran into this error on refresh of my project where upon "npm run dev" -> and reload of my site locally -> I see Compiled /not-found on my command line. And the site itself isnt loaded fully.

Also, none of the animated via framer motion elements are dislayed or animating).

The specific error I see on browser/console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I tried npm install and removing newly inserted packages
I also tried removing most recently added code and packages added to go back to ther era in which it was working
I updated my node version

Link to my repo:
https://github.com/elizzakai/new_portfolio

Images of the error:
[image on browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diRPN.png)

[image of command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq9zV.png)

It does not hit an error that appears on the screen as a pop up. Its more like after loading up the local browser, I notice the framer motion elements arent animating, one in particular being the Intro component  (before the about us section).

Then after, I see this error on console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

And then in command line: Compiled /not-found in 237ms (1192 modules)

Comment: just ran your code and it works without any errors - perhaps you can describe the errors fully, i.e. what resources are failing to load for example

Comment: It does not hit an error that appears on the screen as a pop up. Its more like after loading up the local browser, I notice the framer motion elements arent animating

Then after, I see this error on console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

And then in command line: Compiled /not-found in 237ms (1192 modules)